# Insert parameter and value in var for query-string

Tags: php, query-string

Thats my code:

```
<?php
$data = array('marke'=> $_GET["marke"],
              'farbe'=> $_GET["farbe"],
              'sort'=> $_GET["sort"]);

$parameter = http_build_query($data);
?>
```

I need to insert "farbe=blau" after marke and before sort when farbe is not set

Comment: Why does the order matter?

Comment: Actually, he means, set `farbe` to `blau`, `if (!isset($_GET['farbe']))`

Comment: for seo, i use it as links so its for avoiding double content and what djot said

Comment: I find it highly doubtful whether the order of GET parameters is actually going to matter for SEO. Either way, I guess using  `isset()` and having it construct arrays in one way or the other is the easiest way here. `if isset($_GET["farbe"]) $data = ...; else $data = ...;`

Comment: thats a bit laborious :D isnt there a way to just put it into $parameter?

Comment: You mean as defaults? Sure, but your code does not have "any" feature prepared like this.

Comment: i thought so ^^ well i'll do it with your code, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
  $data = array('marke'=> $_GET['marke'],
                'farbe'=> $_GET['farbe'],
                'sort'=> $_GET['sort']);
  if (!isset($_GET['farbe'])) { $data['farbe'] = 'blau'; }
  $parameter = http_build_query($data);
?>
```